# velocity of liquid in hydraulic motor

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics

Does the speed of liquid in the hydraulic motor eye affects the revolution Per minute of the motor?

So if i changed the diameter of the hose of the motor will this change any thing in the motor?

Comment: Is it axial intake radial ouput motor? Speed in which direction do you have in mind?

Comment: http://hydraulicspneumatics.com/site-files/hydraulicspneumatics.com/files/uploads/2014/06/0714_HydMotors_F1.gif                                                               in a pic like this would the speed of liquid at the inlet change anything

Answer (score 0):

You provide some constant power input to motor. This power is proportional to the product of torque exerted by the motor and its r.p.m. Neglecting losses, power input to the motor goes into two parts: one, raising liquid from sump level to outlet level (outlet is where flow comes out of the pipe into atmosphere), and two, kinetic energy of the flow at the outlet. The only way to reduce (increase) the motor r.p.m. would be to increase (reduce) losses in the flow, say by closing (opening) a valve, which would increase (decrease) torque requirement on motor and thus reduce (increase) r.p.m. Therefore changing hose pipe size (within a reasonable range) does nothing to alter the operating parameters of the pump.